# Google Distance Matrix Coverage - Transit/Tokyo

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-distancematrix-api

I've found that the Google Distance Matrix API returns "ZERO_RESULTS" when I query a transit route in Tokyo. However, according to Google's website they [do have "transit" coverage for Tokyo](https://maps.google.com/landing/transit/cities/#Asia).

Also if I try Google Maps online I can get a route. This is the only city (Seoul works, New Delhi works, Bangkok works, etc.) where I can't get transit directions using the matrix API.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this "issue" in the issue tracker: [Issue 7854:    Bug: Obtain zero_results from direction api in transit mode in Tokyo](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7854), transit data is not (currently) available in Japan:

> Unfortunately transit directions are not currently available for Japan in the Directions and Distance Matrix API (Dec 1, 2015)